# is it possible for HTML DOM parser to extract the line number of its source?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWLCb.jpg)

i want to extract the line number, not jut the source
for example :

```
 foreach($html->find('u') as $element2){
    echo "$element2<br />";
 }
```

is it possible for **element2** to extract the line number also?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DOMNode::getLineNo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.getlineno.php#102771) which works like this:

```
 <?php
// XML dump for below example
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <node />
</root>
XML;

// Create a new DOMDocument instance
$dom = new DOMDocument;

// Load the XML
$dom->loadXML($xml);

// Print where the line where the 'node' element was defined in
printf('The <node> tag is defined on line %d', $dom->getElementsByTagName('node')->item(0)->getLineNo());
?>
```

The above example will output:

> The  tag is defined in line 3.

**FYI:** Some years ago this method stopped working due to libxml2 bug but I did an online fiddle and it worked.